# Set value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the input value to 1 when checking the checkbox and empty when unchecking,
Can't get it to work, please help.

```
<td id="check-box"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"></td>
<td id="qty-box"><input type="text" name="qtybox"></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setValue(a) {
   if (a < 1) {
     a = 1;
   }
}
var qty = $('#qty-box [name="qtybox"]').val();

$("#check-box").click(function() {    
    if ($(this[name = "checkbox"]).attr('checked', true)) {
        setValue(qty);
    }
    else {
        qty = 0;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just a comment. When a form is posted and a `checkbox` is not checked, it is not included in the `POST`. It is only POSTed when it is checked which might be all you are looking for. If you need to know client-side, you can do so by checking this `$("input[name='checkbox']:checked").length == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice and short with a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NG7Xq/)**:

```
$('input[name="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="qtybox"]').val($(this).is(':checked')?'1':'');
})​
```

Comment: One more thing please, How about the reverse, to un-check when the qtybox value is deleted?

Comment: See an updated jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NG7Xq/1/. This unchecks the checkbox if the text field is empty and checks it if it's not.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't check when value is put in to the qtybox. I really appreciate your help, I'm very new to this and programing in general.

Comment: BTW I think you also answered another question for me two weeks ago.

Comment: If i have multiple <tr>'s I do something like this? $('input[name="qtybox"]').keyup(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('input[name="checkbox"]')
    .attr("checked", $(this).val().length > 0);

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure that would do it. Let me see if I can create a quick example.

Comment: Please take a look at my new question, nobody seems to have a clue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811271/calculate-one-td-x-another-td-in-jquery

Comment: May I ask you for some help,                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971913/move-mysql-fetch-array-pointer/10972137#comment14328144_10972137

Answer (score 2):

Try the following -

```
<td id="check-box"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"></td>
<td id="qty-box"><input type="text" name="qtybox"></td>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("input[name='checkbox']").click(function()
        {
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            { 
                $("input[name='qtybox']").val("1");
            }
            else
            {
                $("input[name='qtybox']").val("");  // Change it to - val("0") - 
                                  //if you want to clear the text box with zero.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5rRak/) is a nice little demo of the working version.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
$(function(){

    $('input[name="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        $('input[name="qtybox"]').val(0);
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="qtybox"]').val(1);
        }

    });

});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/PBzuQ/17/

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to the input makes thing much more simple.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="check-box" name="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="qty-box" name="qtybox"></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#check-box").click(function () {
        var qty = $('#qty-box');
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            if (qty.val() < 1) qty.val(1);
        } else {
            qty.val(0);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```