# Calculate one <td> x another <td> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting NaN. How can I do this and have it update every time time qty is changed?

```
$('input[name="qtybox"]').change(function(){
var price = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
* parseFloat($(this).closest('#price').text(), 10);
$("#tPrice").html(price);
});
<td id="price">2.79</td>
<td id="qty-box"><input type="text" name="qtybox"></td>
<td id="tPrice"></td>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through and debugging this to see which part is failing?

Comment: Correct, and that's because I'm waiting for the user to enter quantity

Comment: ID's are singular and cannot be repeated throughout a document. You should consider not using id for 'price' element if there are multiple prices. instead use classes (which can be repeated). If price is the only element with that id then you don't need to 'closest()' anything because $('#price') will return the only value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZENeG/2/)**?

jQuery:

```
$('input.qtybox').each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
        var price = $(this).parent().siblings('td#price').text();
        var qty = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().siblings('td#tPrice').html(isNaN( ((price * qty).toFixed(2)) ) ? 0 : ((price * qty).toFixed(2)));
    })
})
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle is somewhat different from the example. I won't be able to look at this until later but feel free to nudge me if I forget.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I really DO nudge

Comment: Please look at my question.                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219278/php-show-error-messages-in-order-and-re-display-correct-fields  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt()` evaluates to NaN. You're trying to parse an integer from an empty string.

Please provide a more complete code sample; I believe the problem is that you're trying to use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) when you should be using [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 0):

A table cell doesn't have a value. Use the `text` method instead.

Also, parsing the string `2.79` as an integer will give you just `2`.

```
parseFloat($(this).closest('#price').text())
```

Comment: I updated and still getting NaN. Here's the updated code,         $('input[name="qtybox"]').change(function(){
 var price = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
 * parseFloat($(this).closest('#price').text(), 10);
 $("#tPrice").html(price);
});

Comment: @user1157575: You should still use `val()` for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.closest()` looks up the chain. To make things less complicated, just don't specify a boundary:

```
$('#tPrice').each(function(){
    var price = parseInt($('input[name="qtybox"]').val(), 10 * parseInt($('#price').val(), 10);
    $(this).html(price);
});
```

To keep your current model:

```
$('#tPrice').each(function(){
    var price = parseInt($(this).prevAll('input[name="qtybox"]').val(), 10 * parseInt($(this).prevAll('#price').val(), 10);
    $(this).html(price);
});
```

Though you should really never constrain an ID selector unless you have a good reason to, because it can't be optimized if you do so.