# Move mysql_fetch_array pointer

Tags: php, mysql

How can I move mysql_fetch_array pointer in middle of a while loop?
something like this:

```
 while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_qry))
{
 $output = "<div class=\"left\" id=\"{$subject['id']}\"></div>";
  next($subject);
     $output = "<div class=\"right\" id=\"{$subject['id']}\"></div>";
  return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_qry))
{
  if ($counter % 2 == 0)
  {
     $output = "<div class=\"left\" id=\"{$subject['id']}\"></div>";
  }
  else
  {
     $output = "<div class=\"right\" id=\"{$subject['id']}\"></div>";
  }
  // do something with $output here...
  $counter ++;
}
```

Or you could achieve the same result with a boolean:

```
$left = true;
while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_qry))
{
  if ($left)
  {
     $output = "<div class=\"left\" id=\"{$subject['id']}\"></div>";
  }
  else
  {
     $output = "<div class=\"right\" id=\"{$subject['id']}\"></div>";
  }
  // do something with $output here...
  $left = !$left;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the next row in $subject, how does $counter move the pointer?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you just want to do one thing with even-numbered lines, and another thing with odd-numbered, then my code would solve the problem. If that's not it, let us know what you're trying to do... I.e., why do you want to move the pointer on?

Comment: $subject_qry retrieves from the database 10 categories and I wanna float them left and right. (class="left")

Comment: Right -- so it goes left, right, left, right, etc.? So I reckon the code I've suggested does that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that don't make sense about your example. First, you can't use a name with mysql_fetch_array when retrieving the result. Mysql_fetch_array uses the numeric indices, not the column name. Second, you don't return a value from within a looping while statement. You'd either build up a string or echo it as you're progressing through the loop.

Have you tried something like this:

```
$counter = 1;
while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_qry)) {
    echo "<div class=\"left\" id=\"{$subject[0]}\"></div>";
    mysql_data_seek($subject_qry,$counter);
    $subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_qry);
    echo "<div class=\"right\" id=\"{$subject[0]}\"></div>";
    $counter=$counter+2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this while you are extracting the data from the database.  You have not read the next row with `mysql_fetch_array()` yet so you can't just skip to the next one.

You'll have to populate an array with all the results first to manipulate the "index" of the array.  Alternatively you could just execute an additional `mysql_fetch_array()` within your loop to read the next row.